# gradle error The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: gradle, gradlew, gradle-plugin

I get the below error when I try to build the war using gradle.

The stack trace is below  .

The error happens when I add a specific dependency to my war .Is there any way I can find out what is causing this issue ?

The dependency that I am trying to add has many transitive dependencies

```
11:29:56.507 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
11:29:56.507 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed w
ith an exception.
11:29:56.507 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
11:29:56.507 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
11:29:56.507 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Failed to capture snaps
hot of output files for task 'war' during up-to-date check.
11:29:56.507 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not normalize p
ath for file 'D:\\distribution\combined\build\
libs\masters:qams-1.0.0.war'.
11:29:56.507 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
11:29:56.507 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
11:29:56.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.Unchecke
dIOException: Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task 'war' during u
p-to-date check.
11:29:56.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.changedetection.rules.AbstractFileSnapshotTaskStateChanges.createSnap
shotPreCheck(AbstractFileSnapshotTaskStateChanges.java:49)
11:29:56.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.changedetection.rules.OutputFilesTaskStateChanges.saveCurrent(OutputF
ilesTaskStateChanges.java:79)
11:29:56.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.changedetection.rules.AbstractFileSnapshotTaskStateChanges.snapshotAf
terTask(AbstractFileSnapshotTaskStateChanges.java:89)
11:29:56.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.changedetection.rules.OutputFilesTaskStateChanges.snapshotAfterTask(O
utputFilesTaskStateChanges.java:28)
11:29:56.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.changedetection.rules.CachingTaskStateChanges.snapshotAfterTask(Cachi
ngTaskStateChanges.java:84)
11:29:56.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.changedetection.rules.SummaryTaskStateChanges.snapshotAfterTask(Summa
ryTaskStateChanges.java:73)
11:29:56.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifa
ctStateImpl.afterTask(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:134)
11:29:56.509 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExec
uter.java:68)
11:29:56.509 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter
.java:58)
11:29:56.509 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySou
rceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
11:29:56.509 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoA
ctionsExecuter.java:52)
11:29:56.509 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter
.java:53)
11:29:56.509 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOn
ceTaskExecuter.java:43)
11:29:56.509 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ex
ecution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(Default
TaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
11:29:56.509 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ex
ecution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(Default
TaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
11:29:56.509 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ex
ecution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(Abstra
ctTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
11:29:56.509 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ex
ecution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPl
anExecutor.java:50)
11:29:56.509 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.in
ternal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy
.java:54)
11:29:56.509 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.in
ternal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
11:29:56.510 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.a
pi.UncheckedIOException: Could not normalize path for file 'D:\M\combined\build\libs\masters:qams-1.0.0.war'.
11:29:56.510 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.file.FileNormaliser.normalise(FileNormaliser.java:90)
11:29:56.510 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.file.AbstractFileResolver.resolve(AbstractFileResolver.java:82)
11:29:56.510 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.file.AbstractFileResolver.resolve(AbstractFileResolver.java:62)
11:29:56.510 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext$FileCollectionCo
nverter.convertInto(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:162)
11:29:56.510 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(Defaul
tFileCollectionResolveContext.java:123)
11:29:56.510 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileCol
lections(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:81)
11:29:56.510 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext$FileCollectionCo
nverter.convertInto(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:146)
11:29:56.510 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(Defaul
tFileCollectionResolveContext.java:98)
11:29:56.511 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileCol
lections(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:81)
11:29:56.511 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.getSourceCollections(CompositeFileCollec
tion.java:162)
11:29:56.511 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.getFiles(CompositeFileCollection.java:45
)
11:29:56.511 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.changedetection.state.OutputFilesCollectionSnapshotter.getRoots(Outpu
tFilesCollectionSnapshotter.java:71)
11:29:56.511 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.changedetection.state.OutputFilesCollectionSnapshotter.preCheck(Outpu
tFilesCollectionSnapshotter.java:66)
11:29:56.511 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.changedetection.rules.AbstractFileSnapshotTaskStateChanges.createSnap
shotPreCheck(AbstractFileSnapshotTaskStateChanges.java:47)
11:29:56.511 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        ... 18 more
11:29:56.511 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.io.IOEx
ception: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
11:29:56.511 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.ap
i.internal.file.FileNormaliser.normalise(FileNormaliser.java:54)
11:29:56.511 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        ... 31 more
11:29:56.511 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
11:29:56.512 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
11:29:56.512 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
11:29:56.512 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not seem to be related to dependencies.
It more seems that you set `masters:qams-1.0.0.war` as name for the generated WAR file which is not a valid path on Windows as paths must not contain colons, except after the drive letter.
To point to the concrete error you need to provide your buildscript, but maybe this information is already enough for you, thus I post it as answer, not comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Was struggling for the last few hours with the problem. I Should have gone through the stack trace more carefully.